# Testing onErrorResume() Spring Webflux

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a service layer using Spring Webflux and reactor and I am writing unit test for this. I was able to test the good response scenario but not sure how to test `onErrorResume()` using StepVerifier. Also please let me know if there is a better way of handling exceptions in my controller(e.g: using `switchIfEmpty()`)

Here is my controller method

```java
    public Mono<SomeType> getInfo(Integer id) {
            return webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path())
                    .header("", "")
                    .header("", "")
                    .header("", "")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(POJO.class)
                    .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                        if (ex instanceof WebFaultException)
                            return Mono.error(ex);
                        return Mono.error(new WebFaultException(ex.getMessage(), "Error on API Call", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                    });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can mock the webclient and use [Mockito.doThrow](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions) when webclientMock.get() is called.

```java
YourWebClient webclientMock = mock(YourWebClient.class);


doThrow(RuntimeException.class)
      .when(webclientMock)
      .get();

// Call your method here

 Exception exception = assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
        YourController.getInfo(someIntValue);
    });

// If you chose to raise WebFaultException, addittionaly assert that the return values ( message, status) are the one you expected
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to test your `WebClient` code without having to mock the `WebClient` class itself, as that can quickly become very messy, is to build your `WebClient` with an `ExchangeFunction` that returns whatever response or error you expect. I've found this to be a happy medium between mocking out the `WebClient` and spinning up `Wiremock` for unit tests.

```java
    @Test
    void ourTest() {
        ExchangeFunction exchangeFunction = mock(ExchangeFunction.class);
        // this can be altered to return either happy or unhappy responses        
        given(exchangeFunction.exchange(any(ClientRequest.class))).willReturn(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()));        
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .exchangeFunction(exchangeFunction)
                .build();

        // code under test - this should live in your service
        Mono<String> mono = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://someUrl.com")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(POJO.class)
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    if (ex instanceof WebFaultException)
                        return Mono.error(ex);
                    return Mono.error(new WebFaultException(ex.getMessage(), "Error on API Call", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                });

        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .expectError(RuntimeException.class)
                .verify();
    }
```